# Is possible to ignore buffers by major mode?

Tags: helm

Currently I'm ignore these buffers:

```
(setf helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list '("\\` " "\\*helm" "\\*helm-mode"
                                       "\\*Echo Area" "\\*Minibuf" "\\*monky-cmd-process\\*"
                                       "\\*epc con" "\\*Compile-Log\\*" "\\*monky-process\\*"
                                       "\\*CEDET CScope\\*" "\\*Messages\\*" "\\*Flycheck error"
                                       "\\*.+(.+)" "elpa/.+" "tramp/.+"
                                       "\\*Gofmt Errors\\*" "\\*autopep8"
                                       "\\*magit-process:" "\\*magit-diff:" "\\*anaconda-mode\\*"))
```

Ok. I started using Circe for IRC and all that, but it annoys me seeing the buffer of each channel and the buffer of the server in the Helm buffer every time I hit `C-x b`, I feel that my buffer list is cluttered. I'm on the way of using [helm-circe](https://github.com/lesharris/helm-circe) to manage those buffers alone.

So, I was wondering if it where even possible to tell Helm to ignore those buffers that have certain major mode activated, in this particular case, `circe-mode`.

Comment: You can't ignore buffer according to its major mode easily, one way that I can image is to advice the function (such as `helm-skip-boring-buffers`, which is used by helm to help build a buffer list) to skip the major mode as you like.  However, according to my little experimentation, the buffer name created by `circe` is still very specialized (e.g., `irc.freenode.net:6697` and `#emacs`), so it is easy to filter by using their buffer name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a regexp that starts with an asterisk filters out by major mode, exactly what you need. So add `"\\*circe-mode"` to `helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list` list.

(To convince yourself, you can first try it right in the buffer list, by typing `*circe-mode` as the pattern and making sure you see only the buffers you want to filter out.)

Answer (score 1):

The buffer names created by Circe look like `#emacs` and `irc.freenode.net:6697` from here, and the following is how to tell helm to ignore them:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'helm-buffers
  (add-to-list 'helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list "\\`#")
  (add-to-list 'helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list "irc.freenode.net:6697"))
```

As far as I know, there is no easy way to filter according to major mode.